# What happens if you supply too much voltage to an LED?

Tags: arduino-uno

Say I have an LED that requires 3.5v. What happens if I power it with more voltage?

For example, my Arduino Uno has a 5v pin. If I power the 3.5v LED from the 5v pin, what will happen?

Comment: It depends on if there is a resistor in the circuit, and what the impedance of your voltage source is.

Comment: I decided to make a video of this: https://youtu.be/Auuisr9sL-8

Answer (score 5):

In the most simple terms: it will kill the LED.  However things are really not that simple.

First off, an LED is a *current* driven device, not a *voltage* driven device. That is, it doesn't really care what the voltage is, but it does care what the current is.  Of course, too much voltage will kill it - but too much current, regardless of the voltage, will kill it.

It's important to understand that an LED is what is known as a *non-linear component*.  Things like resistors are called *linear* because they have a linear relationship between voltage and current. Increase the voltage, and the current increases by the same proportion. Increase the resistance and the current decreases by the same proportion.

However an LED is not like that. A typical Voltage-vs-Current graph for an LED looks like this:

[image]

Once the voltage reaches the "forward voltage" of the LED the current flowing through it rapidly increases. As you can see it very quickly gets towards infinity. Above a certain point and an increase in voltage has no real difference in the current. In that example the difference between 3V and 5V would be both infinite and zero. In other words, it's pretty meaningless.

But we're still over-simplifying, and that's because we've assumed an *ideal* power supply. That is, one that can supply a fixed voltage, but *infinite* current. In other words, a power supply with *zero impedance*.

No such thing exists, though.

Every fixed-voltage power supply can be seen as an ideal voltage source with an in-line (series) resistor. That resistor limits the amount of current that the supply can provide before the voltage drops too low.  In schematic terms, it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqBiOw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the voltage of the source is above the forward voltage of the LED it will try and draw an infinite amount of current from the source.  That current will lead to a voltage drop across the resistance *RZ*, which results in the output voltage of the source being reduced.

It will reduce to be the same as the forward voltage of the LED.

We can, of course, calculate the current that would come out of the supply if we know the impedance of the source, but that's not something that is often known.  So you assume it's low and take precautions.

For example, if we happen to know the impedance of the source is 1Ω (maybe it's stated in the datasheet for the power source...) and the voltage is 5V, and we have an LED that has a forward voltage of 2V (I like nice round numbers), we can work out that:

- The voltage drop caused by the impedance is 3V (5-2)
- The current that causes that drop is 3A (I=V/R, 3/1=3A)

3A is way off the scale for an LED, and it will basically melt internally.

So we add an extra resistance to drop *more* of the voltage at a lower current.

Now if we take the example of powering an LED directly from an Arduino's GPIO pin without a resistor, we can do the same kind of calculations.

We know that we mustn't draw more than 40mA from a pin (*absolute maximum*), so if we take that as the current that can come out of a pin before it drops below an acceptable level we can work out an estimate of the impedance. Since the datasheet tells us the output level it shouldn't drop below is 4.2V when powered by 5V, we know that the maximum voltage drop at the maximum current would be 0.8V (5-4.2).  So:

- R=V/I = 0.8/0.04 = 20Ω.

There. That's an approximation of the output impedance of a GPIO pin on an Arduino.  So we can plug that into our formulae and connect an LED, and we get:

- The voltage drop caused by the impedance is 3V (5-2)
- The current that causes that drop is 150mA (I=V/R, 3/20=0.15)

150mA is not massive. It's more than an LED typically wants (20-30mA tops), so the LED won't be happy, but it won't instantly blow at that level. It will be brighter than normal, get hotter than normal, and its lifetime will be much much shorter than normal.

That's not the worrying thing though.  The worst thing is the *power dissipation* from the impedance:

- P=I²R = 0.15²×20 = 0.45W.

That's almost half a watt of heat being generated by the GPIO pin's drivers. If you consider that a half-watt resistor is pretty chunky, if you can picture that power being crammed into the tiny space of a single MOSFET within a silicon chip, you can see how that may become a problem.

It's really not capable of dealing with that level of heat, and the GPIO pin's driver MOSFET goes belly up.  Bye bye MOSFET, bye bye GPIO pin.

As an aside, you would probably also see other strange things happening as the chip tries in vain to deliver large currents to a single GPIO pin. Other areas of the chip get starved of power, power rails drop in voltage, code crashes, etc. All from just one little LED being connected without a resistor.