# LED does not light when inserted into round Lilypad board

Tags: led

Title: LED does not light when inserted into round Lilypad board.

very simple goal here: i want to plug in a blinking LED [or 10] into a round circuit board [then solder them], then power those LEDs. when i touch the - and + battery wires to the loose LED it lights. as soon as i insert the LED into the Lilypad round prototype board, those same battery wires will not light the LED. of course when i solder the LED in, then touching the battery - and + to two of the outer board contacts, nothing lights. the board is, "LilyPad Prototype Board ProtoBoard by AMX3d - Round Prototype Board for all DIY Electronics project", and the LEDs are, "100pcs 3mm Flat Top Water Clear Fast Rainbow Flash RGB flashing LED Diodes USA". it is like the board thwarts conductivity. thoughts?

board - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01L9B9RSY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L9B9RSY)

LEDs - https://www.ebay.com/itm/121752435838

Comment: and the resistor? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink

Comment: How is it actually wired?

Comment: wow glad u can get ur "eyes" on this. i have no resistor, why would i need one? one per LED? i literally hold the LED, touch black and red wires to the short and long LED legs, it lights. i then insert it into the board, then w the wires still on the legs, as it is lit, when it goes into the board, it stops lighting. i had soldered a tiny dab on the same edge as where the outer pwr pads show circuit paths going towards center of board, so i think it's soldered on the right side. but then i discovered, merely inserting the LED stops the conductivity. i thought it could NOT be simpler lol.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/what-happens-if-you-supply-too-much-voltage-to-an-led?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: That board looks to me like every pin is connected to every other pin. You will have to isolate the pins you want to use. I have never seen a board like that before...

Comment: the question remains ....  @dcparham, why do you not see that all the pads are connected together on that board?

Comment: well, being an uber noob, i am only now tuning into the context of how the boards work. Majenko below highlighted what i had just found when going back to RTM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your board has every pin directly connected to every other pin.

As it states in the description:

> 10 mil traces connect holes, **cut the ones you do not need** to create a breadboard with infinite possibilities

(Highlighting by me).

Comment: hah, NOW it's making a micron of sense.... so need to use a razor or clippers to isolate away the holes i will not be using; then the board will look strange, parts of it being cut away, right? my original goal was to have a bank of LEDs in a circle, beneath a 1" circle hole in wood, to produce a sparkling effect. i had thought the board would remain circular. anyway, thx much!

Comment: You don't need to cut the board - only the thin tracks that join the holes. Just scape them with a craft knife until they break.

Comment: ah i see, isolate the row and column that lead to their respective outer pad [one -, the other +], by breaking the other connections. new to this, thx much! [but of course let me know if i misinterpreted your notes]

Comment: Sounds right, yes. If you look at the rear you can see that there are 4 traces coming from each pad, north, south, east and west. Should be easy enough to cut them.